# Different shipping prices based on sub total woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need the following.

When a user purchase for under 350 - only pickup allowed
when order is between 350 - 1000 delivery fee of 35 is added
when order is above 1000 - free delivery

I posted the answer below if it may help anyone with similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super simple Solution.
Under shipping methods add one shipping method -> flat rate with 0 as value.
Then in theme function file add this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
    
    if (WC()->cart->subtotal < 350){
    #only pick up
    $new_cost = 0;
    $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    $rates[$key]->label = 'Pick Up Only';   
}

else if (WC()->cart->subtotal >= 350 && WC()->cart->subtotal < 1000) {

    $new_cost = 35;
    $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    $rates[$key]->label = 'Shipping - Deliver fee';
}
else {
    $new_cost = 0;
    $rates[$key]->cost = $new_cost;
    $rates[$key]->label = 'Free Shipping Order above R1000';      
}
        
}

return $rates;

}
```